# Does Mandrill try to resend the bounced emails?

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill

I'm wondering if Mandrill tries to resend the already bounced emails. It's a part of my business flow so I would love to hear feedback from someone competent in this domain. 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

First , check out why so look the resaon , it will be useless most of the time to resend a bounced email : https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582937-What-happens-if-an-email-bounces-

I you want to resend , follow these instructions : http://blog.mandrill.com/resending-messages-rules-actions.html

Comment: Tbh your answer is a bit out of the scope of my question, besides I don't think resend a bounced email would be useless most of the time as for example Mailchimp tries to do that, and temporary issue means that issue is temporary and can be solved in any moment - imo it's completely business decision of Mandrill owner if to do that.

Comment: I meant it's better to see why the email bounced in first time...otherwise most of the time it will be useless to resend directly because you will have a delevery rate around 90% ...most of the time errors come from a client error or something very specific...by resending directly you have great chances to have an another bounced email